# make 64 bit com control with qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make ActiveX from my current source code that have been written in Qt framework and add it to visual studio as a COM control and use it in C#. I have done it with Qt 4.8.6 and Visual Studio 2010 and it worked. However when I change target machine to 64 bit in visual studio, it no longer works. I came across that it compile with a 32 bit dll and I have to compile it with 64 bit dll after that I compile Qt 4.8.6 for VS 2012 64 bit and I compiled it with 64 bit dll successfully and I register it - it registers successfully but when I try to add it as COM control it gives me this error:
Self registration for D:..... .dll faild.
how can I fix this problem?I compile it  with qt 5.0.1 and it was the same.

```
#ifndef OBJECTS_H
#define OBJECTS_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QColor>
QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
class QVBoxLayout;
QT_END_NAMESPACE
class QSubWidget;
class CirclesGraphicsScene;
class CirclesGraphicsView;
//! [0]
class Circles : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_CLASSINFO("ClassID", "{d574a747-8016-46db-a07c-b2b4854ee75c}")
    Q_CLASSINFO("InterfaceID", "{4a30719d-d9c2-4659-9d16-67378209f822}")
    Q_CLASSINFO("EventsID", "{4a30719d-d9c2-4659-9d16-67378209f823}")
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor backgroundColor READ backgroundColor WRITE setBackgroundColor)
    Q_PROPERTY(int circleNumber READ circleNumber WRITE setCircleNumber)

    void createScene();
public:
    Circles(QWidget *parent = 0);

    QSize sizeHint() const;
    QColor backgroundColor()const;
    int circleNumber()const{return _n;}

public slots:

//--general
    void setBackgroundColor(QColor color);
    void setCircleNumber(int n);

//--axes
    //void setAxesPen(QColor color, int w , int penStyle);

//--circles
    void addCircles(int r, int n, int s, int e);
..............
```